# Bootstrap datetimepicker close when another datetimepicker is opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm currently using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

How do we close an opened datetimepicker if I open another datetimepicker?

Because I have 2 datetimepickers and they over lap.

code:

```
$('#picker_start_date').click(function() {
    var start_picker = $("#picker_start_date").find(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget");
    var end_picker = $("#picker_end_date").find(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget")
    if(end_picker.is(":visible")) {
        end_picker.hide();
        start_picker.show();
    }
    else {
        start_picker.show();
    }
})

$('#picker_end_date').click(function() {
    var start_picker = $("#picker_start_date").find(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget");
    var end_picker = $("#picker_end_date").find(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget");
    if(start_picker.is(":visible")) {
        start_picker.hide();
        end_picker.show();
    }
    else {
        end_picker.show();
    }
})
```

I've tried this code above and it's hit and miss. It's not consistent

Comment: Ground control to semicolon.... Come in semicolon.... I'm receiving no response sir.... He's..... Gone :(

Comment: @SteveHarris haha ...well said !

Comment: Datetimepicker closes by default after a `blur` event, so when do your pickers overlap? Can you provide init code for pickers?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pasted your markup. Anyway hope this snippet helps you to achieve the desired functionality.

Say, we have two datepickers with ids datepicker1 and datepicker2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#datepicker1').hide();
   $('#datepicker2').hide(); 
/* Please note that if the css rules are set to display:none !important then it may not hide them */

 $('#datepicker1').click(function(){

  $(this).toggle();
 });

 $('#datepicker2').click(function(){

  $(this).toggle();
 });
});
```

P.S -Please ensure you use seperate ids for diff. datepickers. Have your jquery loaded before it.

Do let me know if you face any trouble !

Comment: Need some quotes around them ids.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Added them.

Comment: this doesn't work it hides.

`datepicker1`

has http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ been abandoned?

there has been no activity on it's github for almost half a year now

Comment: I have updated my answer to add these  lines`$('#datepicker1').hide();
   $('#datepicker2').hide();`  maintained or not it should work as the minimal jquery functions are used which I am sure are compatible for earlier jqueryversions as well.  Let me know if it still doesn't works then I can give an alternative and maintained datapicker to you !